# Using the Sum of neural network outputs as exepected number of positives

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, logistic-regression

I'm working with a single-output neural network using the logistic activation function to classify individuals into classes A and B.  The output for a given individual can be interpreted as the probability that that individual belongs to class A.  If I sum the probabilities for all individuals I should get an estimator for the expected number of individuals in class A.

Indeed, in my experience, summing the outputs of a neural network on its own training set appears to ALWAYS give the number of training set individuals in class A. I'll bet there is a theorem to this effect.

Does anyone know something about the statistics of this estimate for the size of class A?  For example the variance, bias, general distribution? I'd love to know something I can read on this subject.

In my experience, when applied to new data, the estimate does not seem too accurate.